# Don't have access to a file via IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I have deployed a ASP.NET Web Forms Application with the .NET 4.5 Framework on the IIS 7.5. My IIS must have access to local files, edit a Excel-File, create a new and so on. When I run my application I get an error, the ASP.NET don't have the right for this file.

On the Properties Page for this special file I give the IUSR and the IIS_IUSRS the full rights. In a post I have read that in the lusrmgr.msc must be a ASPNET-User, but I don't have such a user. Is the IIS not right installed?

[image: lusrmgr.msc]

Comment: Sometimes, it just takes a reboot after making such changes.

Comment: OK, I start a reboot, hopefully it helps

Comment: Check your Groups in lusrmgr for IIS_IUSERS, if there try to add it in `member of` tab in properties of current user.

Comment: is this user called "current user" N K

Answer (score 0):

On my server, I thought that I could just right click the main folder..."wwwroot" or whatever you have your directory set as, and set the permissions and that would change the permissions for everything. Turns out, my server was a little picky and I had to go in and manually right click the directory that IIS_IUSRS didn't have access to and set the permissions again. For example, if the file that you are being denied access to is located in **"wwwroot/files/excel"** then you should right click and manually check the permissions on first **"files"** then again on **"Excel."**

Comment: the same like before, perhaps I must say, in my case I have my excel files on another directory then the wwwroot. Is this a problem?